# What would happen to a planet that was electrically charged?

Tags: science-based, planets, biology, physics, space

If a planet had such a large imbalance of protons and electrons that it possessed a net negative or positive charge what would happen to it and its solar system?

First, could it be stable, or would it simply disintegrate? Would the charge act against the pull of gravity and make everything on the surface weigh less?

Second, what effect would the charged planet have on its moons, neighboring planets, or sun? Would it polarize them, and how would it affect their orbits?

Third, what would the chemistry and biology be like on the planet's surface? Could life develop. Would the chemical reactions possible be radically different? Would elements exist in different forms?

Finally, what would happen to something that got too close like an explorer's spacecraft?

Comment: I would have to research more for a full answer...but I don't think the setup could exist.  The Earth itself is decently electrically charged, it's the electrical flow through the molten core that results in our magnetic field.  To have the entire planet negative or positively charged...I dunno.   The sun is heavily charged as well.  Need some more research time...it'd be interesting answering this question  with the assumption that this could exist.

Comment: [Here](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01054576) is an article discussing the Earth’s net electric charge which mainly arrives at the result that we cannot measure it. While it’s already 25 years old, there is no literature building upon it which seems to have new information.

Comment: There is also [this article](http://www.rxiv.org/pdf/1008.0071v1.pdf) which is newer but has not been published in a peer-reviewed journal. It estimates the charge of the whole planet (with athmosphere) to be −1 C.

Comment: Lots of things - you could have alot of fun with this - i'm so glad someone is thinking about it! Planets move in a plasma - and through electromagnetic fields of other bodies. The 'fun' comes when they exchange charge. https://watchers.news/2017/08/08/electrical-planetary-scarring/ You can see some of the literal world 'building' well maybe this often just looks like world destruction - https://www.holoscience.com/wp/spiral-galaxies-grand-canyons/ Read Velikovsky 'Worlds in Collision' which is from the start of the space age, a semininal work of non-fiction which inspired the movie "when worl

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't mean to disappoint you but planets are already charged - all bodies in space have a voltage that depends on their immediate environment to the degree that they interact with it through the interplanetary medium, which transfers charge to an extent.

Being isolated most of the time, they develop a potential compared to other objects due to the balances within their immediate environment being satisfied but by not having contact with other objects, their relative potential doesn't balance because their charges don't interact.

This is why in electronics and electrical engineering, two points cannot be compared in terms of their voltage, unless they share a point, usually ground. An example would be two batteries - while the voltage between their ends can be approximately the same (lets say 5V), if they're isolated from each other completely and you place a wire near them with a high enough voltage to overcome air resistance (say, 50 kV), against one there might be a spark, but not against the other, at the same distance (provided you kept the wire at a constant voltage). While this is unlikely to happen in the same room, due to the air balancing out charges through interaction and friction, it *is* possible to observe this difference experimentally. The ground in England is not the same ground as in Italy - but the voltage between the ends of batteries will be.

In much the same way, if two celestial objects where to pass close enough to each other to interact electrically, there would be huge lightning bolts. You don't see this often with asteroids because they don't often pass close enough to other objects and because given enough time in the same environment, their effective potential balances out.

But to answer the question, a planet *can* and *does* have a net charge - it's not something exotic, it would be exotic if it didn't.

1. Celestial objects are too far from each other to interact electrically this way, although they do interact through the interplanetary medium, albeit at a much smaller degree
2. Electricity and gravity don't interact the same way with matter. If a planet had a net charge, everything on it would share that net charge. Unless we're talking about a huge volcano (where events are violent enough to cause lightning), a thunderstorm, a tornado or an earthquake (where separations are again violent and there's a lot of friction involved), you wouldn't see much of a difference. Also magnetism is not electricity - they're related but not the same effect - unless the magnetic poles shifted dramatically (which does happen but never abruptly), you wouldn't notice much changing.
3. It would have as much an effect as it has now, on other bodies - the Sun controls most of what happens with charge within the solar system as it has the most powerful charge flows and emissions. It's hard to imagine a planet having a stronger effect on the charge of its surroundings than the star they orbit. Even if it *were* to happen, only the planet would face the consequences, not even moons.
4. Life would be no different - in fact, lightning is considered to be part of the necessary ingredients to get life and in the primordial Earth, we probably got tons of it all the time. With time, life adapts, the atmosphere stabilizes and things work out fine. The elements would also be the same, chemistry would be the same.
5. If the spacecraft entered the planet's environment too fast, it could get struck by lightning when it enters the higher (near space) layers of the atmosphere. But that would be easy to mitigate by just slowly adjusting its orbit until the potential is equalized, provided the pilot was prepared for this case.

> *Also, check Richard Tingle and supercat's comment's down below for more perspective.*

Comment: Re not seeing any difference because everything has the same charge: in the [van de graph hair sticking up experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=87DqbdqBx8U) all your hairs have the same charge and as a result repel each other. In a ridiculously highly charged situation (and I mean ridiculously) you would expect to see some effects (up to and including a breakup of the planet)

Comment: @RichardTingle The question is about a net charge, not the exact same potential and polarity at all points.

Comment: I'm not sure that changes the overall equation. Lets say the planet had a net charge of -1 trillion volts (lets not discuss how it got that way). Now some points are going to be a little more or a little less than that but the point remains: everything has far too many electrons and the electrons would really rather not be near each other. So in other words if you (again *somehow*) made the net potential of a planet increasingly negative things would be increasingly repulsed from each other and eventually (at a huge potential) the planet would be no more

Comment: To charge something, you have to work electrons into it or out of it. Electrons are also free to move around if there's a powerful enough potential. Even considering the very sparse interstellar medium, we're still talking about charges. Unless you completely disconnect the planet from everything (as in, make it a rogue planet), most of that charge will be released towards the sun, exchanged with protons. Just like if you push against a wall, you slide backwards, if you have too many electrons they'll flow along the easiest path (which is towards the Sun) rather than make matter explode.

Comment: @RichardTingle You'd get lightning and lots of it, but it wouldn't "repel itself" into pieces. Once the charges start leaving Earth, you have a flow.

Comment: O yes the whole thing seems highly highly implausible (marginally less so if you charged the entire solar system but still it would still neutralise eventually), thats not really the point. Its point 2 where you say **if it did happen** "you wouldn't see much of a difference" that I'm debating

Comment: I'm not sure what would cause lightening in this scenario (except when things entered the atmosphere of cause). Electrical effects are all about potential differences and I can't see any reason why the potential differences would be any different from the real earth. On the other hand repulsive effects are all about actual charge which would be huge

Comment: @RichardTingle I don't see this being more than a problem of perhaps a few earthquakes at most - my disagreement is simple: unless the planet exists entirely isolated from everything, there's going to be an easier path. Think of an example, like a wire - if it has a billion volts, does anything happen to it just because it's holding the charge? Not really - if it releases it, it could melt, explode due to heating or more likely release it as an arc, but just _holding_ the charge, seems unlikely to result in repulsive forces that could result in a planet exploding, especially close to a star.

Comment: @RichardTingle There's also a limit to how much charge you can hold in the first place, we can't just extend the imbalance indefinitely.

Comment: I've got out [newtons law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation) and [colombs law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) and calculated the charge it would take to overcome gravity and I've come up with a very suprising result. Every kg of matter would require only 0.09 **nano** colombs of charge per kg (9*10^-11 C/kg) to completely overcome gravity. Of course that wouldn't breakup the rocks etc but all air, water, soil and other loose material would be lost at that point. For context static charges by rubbing are generally in the micro colomb range

Comment: @RichardTingle I can't and won't argue with that; +1 for doing the math - the question remains, why does the charge stay there when it's high enough to overcome the resistance of a near vacuum, which would be an easier path? When it comes to small charges, their potential isn't high enough to create connections and circuits across air, so they stay confined within that place and cause their effects - If you confined all that charge and prevented it from escaping then _yes_ you might get the atmosphere to evaporate - the problem is, it's hard to confine it unless you have a disconnected system.

Comment: Indeed, in fact the evaporating atmosphere would make it even harder to maintain the isolation (and the energy requirements to charge the planet would be hilarious). The maths works out that way because gravity is stageringly weak compared to other forces (the fact that a charged hair or small magnet can hold something up against a whole planet's gravity highlights this

Comment: A lot of particles, some of which are charged, enter and leave the Earth continuously.  If the Earth had a significant positive net charge, that would increase the rate at which negatively-charged particles are captured by the Earth's gravitational field, as well as the rate at which positively-charged ones leave.

Comment: @supercat I think I agree, if I understand correctly, but is this just an addition? a correction? I don't understand if you were going somewhere with this.

Comment: Explain the downvote please.

Comment: I'll have to express some skepticism, at least as far as the "huge lightning bolts" are concerned, if only because you don't actually get lightning in vacuum. You can get [vacuum arcing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_arc), but that's a rather different effect. Of course, I suppose a sufficiently intense vacuum arc might sort of look like lightning from a distance, insofar as there'd be an electric discharge and a flash of light, but if you're imagining a lightning bolt zig-zagging through space, that's not really plausible.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I'm not imagining a zig-zag bolt, just a discharge whatever shape it should take in that case.

Comment: A possible idea for a point #6, if you think it sufficiently relevant.

Comment: @richardtingle I don't follow.   Why doesn't my comb fly away if it has orders of magnitude more change more?

Comment: @jdlugosz Because it's still a relatively small charge vs the entire planet. If the entire planet is charged (to a lower density but still a huge total) it's a whole planet of gravity vs a whole planet of charge. The fact the comb reacts at all shows gravity is weak

Comment: Ok, so an experiment in empty space would show the static repulsion overwhelming the gravitational attraction between the combs.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yes, I think something like "plasma stream" would be closer to the mark.  There is a lot of electrical interaction between Io and Jupiter, which manifests as aurorae, ion currents in space, ejections of salt particles and other weird things, but no lightning.

Comment: http://adsbit.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/nph-iarticle_query?bibcode=1955IAUS....2...46S&db_key=AST&page_ind=0&data_type=GIF&type=SCREEN_VIEW&classic=YES - On astronomical scale, *"We can regard conductivity as infinite"*, part about stellar bodies being isolated is iffy, at best.

Answer (score 6):

The [earth](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/91556/is-the-earth-negatively-or-positively-charged) already has a minor negative charge.  This is what causes [lightning](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100929082548AA6zwU8).  However, overall the planet is very close to neutral when combined with the atmosphere.

I do not believe that an electrically charged planet would be stable.  The electromagnetic force is orders of magnitude stronger than gravity.  If the planet were charged, I believe the planet would immediately stabilize.  There are so many free electrons and other particles coming from the sun that the planet could use to revert to neutral.

Even if a planet didn't quickly revert to a neutral charge, how could you create a charge on a planet?  The electromagnetic force is [effectively conserved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_conservation).  (Technically you can could chuck unwanted charge into a black hole and get an imbalance that way but that's a whole other can of worms.)  Electrons and protons come in a pair and the electromagnetic force is very strong.  What force would strip the protons and electrons apart, leaving one on the planet and driving the other far enough away that it didn't merge back into the planet?  Given this, I don't know of any way to generate a large enough charge on a planet to be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Sure, a planet could have “a few” too many or too few electrons to be exactly neutral, but such would be on the same order of magnitude as the separation of charges within different parts of the planet.

If you're thinking of a charged planet throwing lightning bolts to other worlds, or having electromagnetism play a noticeable role in its orbit (like in some of the later works of James P. Hogan), that would not happen.  A strong charge would neutralize itself far faster than geologic time scales.

Consider an airless body like our moon.  It is bombarded by particles from the solar wind, and UV radiation can knock out electrons.  Why doesn't the moon build up a charge that keeps growing for billions of years?  At some point incoming charged particles won't stick but bounce away, and charged particles are shed.

In a body like the Earth, the geomagnetic field shields against most of the solar wind, but if the Earth somehow had a large charge, it would preferentially lose charged particles in the air that slowly leaks away to space; or would strongly repel charged gas molecules and outgas quite rapidly.

Comment: I would expect that many bits of stuff in space have small positive or negative charges.  If a planet had a really large positive charge, that would reduce the number of positively-charged bits of space junk hitting it, while increasing the number of negative ones, to the point that the net charge on the planet was comparable to the average charge on the bits of space junk hitting it.

Comment: You're not going far enough--a charged body will actively draw in opposite charges and actively repel like charges.  Note that this has actually been proposed as a means of radiation-shielding spacecraft.  Put a high power electron accelerator on the spacecraft, use it to toss off electrons, generating a positive charge.  Lets say you charge your spacecraft to 100 million volts: every electron that hits it has +100MeV of energy and every nuclear particle (proton/alpha/etc) loses 100MeV of energy.  The electrons are much easier to shield against, the radiation exposure goes down.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers are correct in saying that (a) celestial bodies generally do have a non-zero charge and (b) if a planet were very strongly charged then it would quickly suck opposite-charged particles from the solar wind until it was approximately neutralised.

But suppose an Earth-like planet *did* magically have a strong permanent negative charge.  You have a surplus of electrons, which repel each other, so broadly they will try to spread out as thinly as possible.  If the charge is completely evenly distributed, then things aren't so different to Earth, except that the ground voltage is much lower than on Earth, though you wouldn't know it unless you ran a cable between the two planets.

The excess electrons mean that the formation of negative ions is easier, and the formation of positive ions is harder.  So I guess, crudely speaking, the planet will be a little more alkaline.  The relative rates of various chemical reactions will be slightly different, but all the same chemistry will exist.

Weather would be different.  Because different gases can hold different amounts of charge per unit mass, I believe the movement of wind would cause the excess charge to become unevenly distributed, resulting in lightning.  Also, the atmosphere would eject more gas into space – the negatively charged planet will repel negatively-charged gas ions.  (This is also one of the ways the planet would shed its excess electrons IRL, but we are stipulating that the electrons get replaced somehow).  Because of this, the atmosphere would be thinner.

Answer (score 1):

While the other answers covered this realistically I think you can take another spin on it. For a **large** net charge I believe you'd have some interesting effects. (the following is based off logical reasoning on the bold item scaled up to planetary sizes).

**Thinking of the atom:**
It would be stable up to a very large charge just due to the weight. At larger charges the the center might become less dense but the surface gravity would not be effected.

**Thinking of an electric generator:**
If objects were oppositely charged they'd probably generate magnetism in the negative object, huge electrical storms, and possibly arcs if close enough. They would at the very least generate an ion stream. It would change the distances and speeds of the orbits but would not effect the shape.

**Thinking of Ionizing Radiation:**
Life doesn't like ions and you have a lot of them flying around, especially if the flow is *from the planet* instead of *from the sun*. So you'd probably have none of it. As the percentage of charged particles increased the chance of forming compounds would go down as nothing would be forming ionic bonds and two ions don't really like to form covalent ones. I don't know about planetary-sized objects, but at least for star-sized ones you'd have some very different materials than normal in the core, as they would bond despite charge.

**Thinking Dust Wiper:**
We have materials such as microfiber which exhibit electrostatic adhesion (there's a name for this type of material if someone can find it), and your charged objects would behave just like them, pulling in oppositely charged objects and probably trying to ionize the other object and end up pulling it in anyway (like amber does when it exchange charge). So expect any passing ships to stick to your planet like tape.

Answer (score -4):

Well, if you live in Europe, you might see three holes in the plug in the wall.
The bottom one is GND (Ground). It is connected to earth. It is meant to be so, so if a lightning strikes the building, it will not pass the charge to US but to EARTH.
The earth's core is filled with liquid metal, and this generates some electric charge, mostly negative one - it has more protons that electrons. The earth itself is generating electricity, and some of it comes from our activity as humans, and lightnings.

Best of Regards,
Itay
Tip: In a lightning storm - never play golf :)

Comment: You cannot generate negative electric charge without also generating positive electric charge, as electric charge is a conserved quantity. Thus the only way to negatively charge the earth is to send positive charges into space or to receive negative charges from space (which actually happens).

Comment: The science here could use some work.

Comment: Stack Exchange questions and answers do not start or end with a greeting. The context is clear so a question or answer can stand alone.

Comment: The earth wire is to protect against insulation failure in the device, not against lightning strikes.

Comment: Only the outer part of Earth's core is liquid, the inner part is solid. If the liquid part had more protons than electrons that would give a positive charge.

Comment: This does not address the question of what would happen to a planet that has an electrical charge. As such it would be better as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: I'm aware this is a lot of feedback at once. It isn't intended to be negative. Once you hit 20 reputation (2 upvotes on an answer or 4 upvotes on a question) you can join us in the site [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/worldbuilders-general-chat) and ask about anything else you want to know. In the meantime, keep asking and answering questions and welcome to worldbuilding...